# How to check distribution of prices in a column

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I am currently working on developing a segmentation model using retail data.

In this dataset, the columns represent different subcategories. The values in these columns indicate the prices of all the products belonging to each respective subcategory.

the data contains around 500 subcategories and I want to check how many of these subcategories have a good distribution of prices and have no skewness. Could some one please explain in detail how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! If you want to check the subcategories for skewed data, it seem like you can just calculate the skewness for each column. There is a straightforward software implementation of this in a loop, and alternatives may provide faster performance but are not considered on-topic here. However, why do you care about the skewness? How will a subcategory being skewed or not influence downstream work?

Comment: Hi Dave, Thankyou very much for the reply !

Comment: It may not be correct to use all the subcategories to segment the customers as many of these subcategories doesn't have a good price distribution and when the price distribution is not good, using that subcategory to segment the customer might not be a good idea, hence I want to filter those subcategories that doesn't have good price distribution .

Comment: Also, if a subcategory is skewed (it means that most of products in that subcategory lie towards either high price or low price) . so when a subcategory doesn't cover enough of all of kinds of price points , it might not be correct to consider that subcategory, hence I want to filter the subcategories that have skewness.

Please correct me if my approach is wrong.

Comment: $1)$ What is a "good" price distribution? $2)$ How are you using that price distribution? $3)$ What is there to this besides calculating the kurtosis values? It sure seems like, if you want to know the distribution kurtosis values (for whatever reason), you can just calculate them.